# How to Access a Custom Azure Registered ML Model in the Azure ML Studio Notebook

Tags: azure, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service, azuremlsdk

I have a custom-trained ML model registered in azure ml studio. The model was built using sklearn trained via azure cli from azure devops.
Model:
[image]

I didn't use Mlflow for the training script, instead, I used the azure ml SDK. A pickle file of the model is also stored in the artifact folder.

[image]

How can I load this model to my azure notebook in Azure ML Studio?

When I ran:

```
client = mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient()
for model in client.list_registered_models():
    print(f"{model.name}")
```

The Model name is displayed, but I cannot access it using **mlflow.<flavor>.load_model() or mlflow.pyfunc.load_model()**.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

When we need to use the model in notebook, we can perform this operation in four different patterns.

1. A path on your local computer
2. Path on Azure ML Datastore
3. Path from ML job
4. Path from MLFlow job

Only few supported types are there for this operation. We can perform using:

a.  Custom file for input

b.  Custom folder for input

c.  Mlflow for input

d.  Custom file for output

e.  Custom folder for output

f.  Mlflow for output

The ML model registration will allow you to create the version of the model. The model was created like below.

[image]

Go to artifacts and we can get the information of the registered model.

[image]

Get the pkl file and click on download all. We will get the files related to the model.

From the cli we need to use the following code block

```
az ml model create --name my-model --version 1 --path azureml://datastores/myblobstore/paths/models/cifar10/cifar.pt
```

if we want to register our model to access through the notebook. Implement the below code block

```
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Model
from azure.ai.ml.constants import ModelType

cloud_model = Model(
    path= "azureml://datastores/workspaceblobstore/paths/model.pkl"
    name="cloud-path-example",
    type=ModelType.CUSTOM,
    description="Model created from cloud path."
)
ml_client.models.create_or_update(cloud_model)
```

[image]

[image]

If we need new model registration, follow the approach.

[image]